# yii2 FileHelper::findDirectories option 'only' not working

Tags: file, yii2, directory

I would like to use the new FileHelper::findDirectories function. Therefore their is an option called 'only'. With this option only results with given value should be returned.

```
$rootpath = Yii::$app->basePath . '/web/';
// in the root path there are some example sub directories eg. 3, 5
if (FileHelper::findDirectories($rootpatg, ['only' => ['4'],'recursive' => false])) {
     echo 'directory found';
} else {
// create directory
     echo 'directory not found';
}
```

In my case FileHelper::findDirectories get also results, even the directory does not exist! For me, this means the option 'only' is not working properly.

Or is there something wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`only` option is available only for `findFiles()` method. See [`findDirectories()` method docs](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.14/framework/helpers/BaseFileHelper.php#L483-L499).

You can try to use `filter` option in configuration, something like:

```
'filter' => function ($path) {
    return strpos($path, '4') !== false;
},
```

In this example method returns only directories with character `4` in the full directory path.

Comment: Ok! How is the correct procedure to check whether a directory exists? For me it is not working!

Comment: You can use `filter` option to match the directories you need.

Comment: Yes, I tried it but I cannot get it to run. Could you give me an example for the filter option, thx!

Comment: umm @Bizley wont it return true if any of the directories names contains `somename4` and we want to find the directory whose name is `4`.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam yes, but this was just an example, you can easily modify it for your needs.